# Remove Underline from MaterialPicker Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker

[image: Viusal = "Material"]

How to remove the underline from Material Picker Control in Xamarin Forms ?

```
            Control.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
```

has no effect

Comment: https://alexdunn.org/2017/07/24/xamarin-tip-borderless-picker/

Comment: It seems  MaterialPicker has its default style,if you want remove the underline,you could use the default picker ,then it will work in your renderer